# Expo Font only displaying custom font in first screen on Android. iOS is working properly

Tags: expo, react-native

My app is running Expo Font correctly on iOS but not on Android. I've also tried replacing loadAsync with useFonts according to the [docs](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/font/) to no avail. I have two separate stylesheets with a baseFont property setting the custom font, but the font is not being read properly for some reason on the other screens. The non-login screens are located in different stacks using React Stack Navigation (@react-navigation/stack). This is basically what the code looks like:

App.js:

```
import RootStack from './navigations/RootStack';
import mainReducer from './reducers/index';
import { getAsyncStorage } from './actions/AuthActions';

const store = createStore(mainReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));
store.dispatch(getAsyncStorage());

export default () => {
  const [fontLoaded, setFontLoaded] = useState(false);

  async function loadResourcesAsync() {
    await Promise.all([
      Font.loadAsync({
        'custom-font': require('./assets/fonts/custom_font.ttf');
      }),
    ]);

    setFontLoaded(true);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    loadResourcesAsync();
  });

  if (!fontLoaded) return (null);
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <RootStack />
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

styles/Login.js:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  baseFont: {
    fontFamily: 'custom-font',
  },
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the answer was particular to `fontWeight` in a stylesheet. Since the custom font didn't have a `bold` typeface embedded in the .ttf, I had to download the bold version and remove `fontWeight: bold` from the css.